# How can I formulate a POST request for an API in Python?

Tags: python, api, mitmproxy

I have a MITMproxy data capture resulting in the following output.

```
POST
https://gateway.monster.com/seeker/mobile/jobs/search/solr?since=946677600&options=applymethod,calculatedistance

Accept:           application/json                                            
Content-Type:     application/json                                            
User-Agent:       monster/2.12.0/800/iOS;10;iPhone-5s                      
Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate                                               
x-domain:         mobileservice.ge.monster.ch                                 
x-brand:          1                                                           
x-ver:            2.12.0                                                      
x-uid:            64e0a64c-ddb5-489c-ab5f-0dec9fed1066                        
x-device:         11                                                          
x-device-model:   iPhone 5s                                                    
x-os-ver:         10                                                      
Content-Length:   313                                                         
Host:             gateway.monster.com

JSON
{
"AgentId": 0,
"CompanyName": "",
"CompanyXCode": "",
"Country": "US",
"Filters": {
    "CareerLevels": [],
    "EducationLevels": [],
    "JobBoardIds": [],
    "JobTypes": [],
    "PostingDuration": -1,
    "YearsOfExp": []
},
"JobTitle": "",
"Keywords": "business",
"Latitude": 0.0,
"Longitude": 0.0,
"Page": 1,
"PageSize": 25,
"Radius": 10,
"Sort": "dt.rv.di",
"Where": "Zurich"
}
```

I tried to replicate that with python in doing the following: POST-URL, attaching the JSON data to the query and setting the header.
However, this results in a bad request error: `<Response [400]>`
I suspect it to be somewhere in the URL part of: `since=946677600&options=applymethod,calculatedistance`

Can anyone tell me what I do wrong?

This is the python code:

```
import requests
import json
import time
from datetime import datetime
import os
from random import randint

#query

url = 'https://gateway.monster.com/seeker/mobile/jobs/search/solr?  
since=946677600&options=applymethod,calculatedistance'
payload = {
  "AgentId": 0,
  "CompanyName": "",
  "CompanyXCode": "",
  "Country": "US",
  "Filters": {
      "CareerLevels": [],
      "EducationLevels": [],
      "JobBoardIds": [],
      "JobTypes": [],
      "PostingDuration": -1,
      "YearsOfExp": []
  },
   "JobId": "",
   "JobTitle": "",
  "Keywords": "software developer",
  "Latitude": 0.0,
  "LocationDescription": "new york",
  "Longitude": 0.0,
  "Page": 1,
  "PageSize": 25,
  "Radius": 20,
  "Sort": "dt.rv.di",
  "Where": "new york"
}

headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}

# Get a copy of the default headers that requests would use
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

# Update the headers with your custom ones
# You don't have to worry about case-sensitivity with
# the dictionary keys, because default_headers uses a custom
# CaseInsensitiveDict implementation within requests' source code.
#userAgents 
headers.update(
  {
      'User-Agent': 'Monster/2.12.0/800/iOS;10.2.1;iPhone-6',
  }
)

 #get the query result from the url with UA set for a ALL jobs in current location
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
print(response)
```

Comment: Try `requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)`

Comment: Thanks. This results now in a 500 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the query with as identical parameters to the capture as possible first. When run with the full set of headers from the capture

```
headers = requests.utils.default_headers()

headers_str = """Accept:           application/json                                            
Content-Type:     application/json                                            
User-Agent:       monster/2.12.0/800/iOS;10;iPhone-5s                      
Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate                                               
x-domain:         mobileservice.ge.monster.ch                                 
x-brand:          1                                                           
x-ver:            2.12.0                                                      
x-uid:            64e0a64c-ddb5-489c-ab5f-0dec9fed1066                        
x-device:         11                                                          
x-device-model:   iPhone 5s                                                    
x-os-ver:         10                                                      
Content-Length:   313                                                         
Host:             gateway.monster.com"""

for l in txt.splitlines():
    k, v = l.split(':')
    headers[k] = v.strip()
```

the response changes to 200.

By trial and error you can then determine that the required header was `x-domain: mobileservice.ge.monster.ch`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I had to include the complete header 1:1 in the query, but your answer put me right in front of the target